# Align an image div in the vertical center of a text div next to it

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I'm editing a Mailchimp template and I was trying to align two divs next to each other, which I accomplished sucessfully. The div on the left is filled with text, the div on the right features 4 images. Now I want to align this image grid vertically to the text, but it should change dynamically. So if the text gets longer, the image position should change and should always stay in the vertical center of the text.

```css
.mcnTextContent {
  position: relative !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.mcnTextContent {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.mcnTextBlockOuter {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.mcnTextBlockInner {
  padding: 0px !important;
  background-color: white;
}

.positionr {
  position: relative !important;
}

.textcolumn {
  width: 370px;
  float: left;
  height: auto !important;
}

.textcolumn h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black !important;
  font-family: "Arial" !important;
  font-weight: initial;
}

.textcolumn p {
  font-family: "Arial" !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.imagecolumn {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 125px;
}

.imagecolumn img {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="positionr">
  <div class="textcolumn">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Body</p>
  </div>

  <div class="imagecolumn">
    <img />
    <img /><br />
    <img />
    <img />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Carefull with your commas, I've fixed the one missing after "Arial" `.textcolumn p {
  font-family: "Arial" !important;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to remove the float and use a wrapper instead: https://jsfiddle.net/qhf8Lczg/1/

```css
.mcnTextContent {
  position: relative !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.mcnTextContent {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 10px !important;
}

.mcnTextBlockOuter {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.mcnTextBlockInner {
  padding: 0px !important;
  background-color: white;
}

.positionr {
  position: relative !important;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.textcolumn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 370px;
  height: auto !important;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.textcolumn h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black !important;
  font-family: "Arial" !important;
  font-weight: initial;
}

.textcolumn p {
  font-family: "Arial" !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.imagecolumn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.imagecolumn img {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="positionr">
  <div class="textcolumn">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an doming bonorum pri, ferri oratio malorum pro et, per tritani phaedrum consulatu in. Vix ei persius assentior, omnes volumus pri id. Eos odio altera dictas no. Erat omnium nominati vix eu, sit et commune pertinacia. Id
      laudem officiis referrentur vix.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="imagecolumn">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" /><br />
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal for a solution :

```css
.positionr {
  position: relative !important;
  background: orange;
}

.textcolumn {
  background: teal;
  height: auto !important;
}

.textcolumn h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black !important;
  font-family: "Arial" !important;
  font-weight: initial;
}

.flex-container {
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container p {
  width: 370px;
  font-family: "Arial" !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  color: black !important;
}

.imagecolumn {
  background: blue;
}

.imagecolumn img {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="positionr">
  <div class="textcolumn">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <p>Donec consequat nulla ut odio sagittis interdum. Maecenas porttitor faucibus congue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam dictum nulla vitae leo mollis, ac sollicitudin erat tincidunt. Nam vel odio mauris. Aliquam vitae
        lectus condimentum, auctor orci a, varius elit. In metus purus, egestas tincidunt ligula at, dapibus imperdiet elit. Nam leo leo, sodales vel justo sed, egestas eleifend ante. Aliquam consectetur nisl odio, sit amet volutpat ante fringilla non.
        Sed in massa sem. Integer sit amet ultricies massa. Aenean eu ullamcorper libero. Aliquam malesuada, mauris a commodo dapibus, leo dui volutpat enim, a elementum nulla dolor eu lacus. Sed venenatis leo nec rutrum tempor. Integer quis rutrum purus,
        rhoncus fringilla odio.</p>

      <div class="imagecolumn">
        <img />
        <img /><br />
        <img />
        <img />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

### How to do it ?

1. Create a flexbox container :

   ```
   <div class="flex-container">
   </div>

   .flex-container {
     display: flex;
   }
   ```
2. Set `align-items: center` (vertically centers both image and text container).
3. Remove

   ```
   float: right;
   padding-top: 125px;
   ```

*Note: background colors are only here for the sake of seeing the boxes, you are free to remove it.*

---

References:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Your solution is a valid answer if it was for a normal html site. However, the user mentioned they are editing an email template. Sadly, email templates need to be written with a lot of very outdated rendering engines in mind (looking at you, Outlook 2007), so flexbox can not be used at this point in time. See this link for reference: https://hashnode.com/post/can-we-use-css-flexbox-in-html-emails-cimofeksh00a0ao53uqeyht5i

Comment: It's a very well written answer otherwise :) It's just a shame many email clients are still so far behind technology wise so we have to rely on hacks and workarounds instead of doing it the nice and proper modern way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `flex` on parent

```
.positionr {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
   }
```

Comment: Please see my comment above, OP is looking for a solution that is safe for email templates. Most email clients are currently not able to support flexbox, sadly.